# IRC : Command to get the channels that I joined

Tags: irc

Is there an IRC command to know the channels that I am currently in?

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2812

Comment: I am unable to find what I am looking for in this RFC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such command directly.

You could use WHOIS then look for numeric reply RPL_WHOISCHANNELS  (numbered 319), splitting the text at spaces to determine your channel list.

See: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459#section-4.5.2